# How can I prove this theorem about limits of intermediate form(0/0 form)?

Tags: calculus, limits

For function $f(x), g(x)$, When $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\alpha$
1. $\lim\limits_{x \to a}g(x) = 0 \implies \lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x) = 0$
2. $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x) = 0 \land \alpha\neq0 \implies \lim\limits_{x \to a}g(x) = 0$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If both $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exist, then

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} \left[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} g(x)\right] = \left[\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right]\left[\lim_{x\to a} g(x)\right]$$

2. If both $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \ne 0$ and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exist, then

$$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{f(x)/g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\to a} f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$$

Comment: Direct and simple approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

For the first part note that $$f(x)=g(x)\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$$

Thus taking the limit gives $$lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0\alpha =0$$

For the second part notice that $$g(x)=f(x)\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$$

Thus $g(x)$ approaches $0 (1/{\alpha})=0$

Answer (score 0):

If the denominator of a limit tends to zero then obviously numerator should also tend to zero  **if**  the limit exists. You can prove by this reasoning.  You can take cases:
1.  If f(x) tends to finite non-zero number then limit would not exist
2.   If f(x) tends to infinity then again limit does not exist.
3.   If f(x) tends to zero then only the limit may exist.
So if it is given the limit exists then only possible case is 3rd.
Similarly if numerator tends to zero
1. If denominator tends to finite non zero number or tends to infinity then limit is zero which is not the case
2. If denominator tends to zero, then only non zero limit may exist. Since it is given the limit exists, this is the only possible case.